# coloring a text letters with css, WITHOUT change HTML code

Tags: css

I'm a starter in css, and today i got a school task:

Here is this HTML code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ABC</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS part */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>ABC</p>
</body>
```

My task is to color "A" letter to #ec407a
"B" to #ffb300
"C" to #26a69a without changing the html code.

How can i manage that?
Thank you guys!

Comment: You cannot. For the A you could go with pseudo selector `p:first-letter`, but there is no way to differentiate between the B and C from a CSS perspective.

Comment: You can achieve this only using Javascript, and obviously you have to change the HTML.

Comment: How about showing us your instructor's question verbatim, I'm curious.

Comment: @Bellu how this can be achieved using js but not changing the HTML?

Comment: @laaposto There's no way, i edited my question.

Comment: @Bellu He can achieve this with css. using `span`. You are still saying "only javascript."

Comment: @connexo it is suppose to be doable via `background-clip: text;` and `mix-blend-mode` can do the trick if you did not flag your FF. Yes, IE still needs to improve itself :)

Answer (score 3):

Serious hack, but here you go

```
<style>
p {
  color:#ffb300;
  position: relative;
}
  p:first-letter {
    color: #ec407a;
  }
  p::after {
    bottom: 0;
    color: #26a69a;
    content: 'C';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
</style>
<body>
    <p>ABC</p>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fqu9ppL4/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) if it was covered by most of the browsers, but [unfortunately](http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode) .. not yet.

So for the futur, this might be a way :

```css
p {
  margin:1em;
  display:table;
  position:relative;
  background:white;/*
  or hudge white inset white shadow to cut off colors 
   box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 100px white; */
  }
  p+p {
  font-size:3em;
  font-family:'Courier New', Courier, modern, monospace;
  
}
p:before {
  content:'';
  background:linear-gradient(to left, #ec407a ,33.33%, #ffb300 33.33%,#ffb300 66.66%, #26a69a 66.66%);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  mix-blend-mode:screen;
}
```

```html
<p>What about a few more letters ?</p>
<p>WIW</p>
```

[image: colorized text]

---

there is also

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

```css
p {
  font-size:3em; /* demo purpose any size */
  display: table;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ec407a, 33.33%, #ffb300 33.33%, #ffb300 66.66%, #26a69a 66.66%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p>ABC</p>
```

Comment: You changed the HTML.

Comment: @connexo where did I ? a single  paragraph is still a single paragraph

Comment: You inserted a blank after each character.

Comment: @connexo ah okay, updated the snippets, but that makes no diiference, background was set on % value for the colors ;)

Comment: So change the string to WIW now :D

Comment: @connexo in that case , you do need to use a monospace font , so each font uses the same space , try use a cursive you'll also get funny result. If you have hand on the HTML or use javascript to modify it, then anything can be done. That was not the question ;)

Comment: There is a serious doubt as to the validity of OP's question as it pertains to  his instructor's question.

Comment: @zer00ne *coloring a text letters with css, WITHOUT change HTML code* it seemed clear to me but my english understanding is average :)

Comment: @GCyrillus, no your comprehension of English is good, read the comments at my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41743107/2813224). No big deal, I just don't like it when someone is dishonest to people who offer to help.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a possible "solution" which is extremely hack-style and works only for the given characters in the given font.

```css
p { 
  color: #ec407a;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 6em;
}
p:after {
  background-color: white;
  content: 'B';
  color: #ffb300;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: -1.33em;
}
p:before {
  content: 'C';
  color: #26a69a;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: -1.335em;
}
```

```html
<p>ABC</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ABC</title>
    <style>
        p::first-letter {
            color: #ec407a;
        }
    </style>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        var text = "ABC";
        var colors = new Array("#ec407a", "#ffb300", "#26a69a");
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    document.write("<span style=\"color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";\">" + text[i] + "</span>");
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>ABC</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I agree with above comment because as per my knowledge no any option